# Formula is giving error when I add "text"

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I'm trying to write a Macro that will do the formatting of a report. All is well up until I try to create the transaction reference number.

The formula basically goes =A2 & "-" & B2 & "ABCD"

When I insert this into my macro it becomes

Range("C2").Formula = "=A2 & "-" & B2 & "ABCD""

As soon as I add my hyphen or the letters at the end it gives me "Compile Error: Expected: end of statement"

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: So the output would be contentOfA2-contentOfB2 ABCD

Comment: `activecell.formula = "=A2 & ""-"" & B2 & ""abcd"""`

Answer (score 2):

Try this.  When adding quotes inside a string, double up the quotes so the program knows you aren't simply ending the string.

```
Range("c2").Formula = "=A2 & ""-"" & B2 & ""ABCD"""
```

Example..

```
Range("A1").value = "adding a quote inside a string ""so and so said something"" is like this."
```

output:  adding a quote inside a string "so and so said something" is like this.

Comment: So I have actually tried this, and it gives me Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object defined error.

Comment: Fixed! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it reversed - e.g. write the formula in excel like this:
[image]

Then select the formula and write the following in the VBA:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Debug.Print Selection.Formula

End Sub
```

On the direct window you would have this:
`=A2&"-"&B2&"abcd"`
This input should be edited a bit, because it comes from the console and you need to escape the `"`. Like this:
`"=A2 & ""-"" & B2 & ""abcd"""`

You can elaborate further, by writing `Debug.Print Selection.FormulaR1C1`, if you need it.

At the end, you can use something like this, to escape the counting of the parenthesis. It would work ok:

```
Public Sub PrintMeUsefulFormula()

    Dim strFormula  As String
    Dim strParenth  As String

    strParenth = """"

    strFormula = Selection.Formula
    strFormula = Replace(strFormula, """", """""")

    strFormula = strParenth & strFormula & strParenth
    Debug.Print strFormula

End Sub
```

It changes the single quote to a double and then it puts the formula in a quote. In my code, it is code `strParenth`.

Comment: So it works perfectly when I type it in. it's only once I put it into my macro it causes me grief.

Comment: Although I could have sworn I did this earlier, this fixes it! Thanks so much! I'm relatively new to VBA and this is my first official use of it.