# How to use vlookup (the formula) to search for string in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

Hi everyone I have a problem with VBA when I try to use vlookup formula like this:

```
Range("H21").Formula = "=VLOOKUP("cleared",'mortgage'!A2:F12,4,FALSE)"
```

it keeps telling me the part "cleared" is an syntax error. Can someone tell me how to deal with that? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

double the quotes:

```
Range("H21").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(""cleared"",'mortgage'!A2:F12,4,FALSE)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your VBE thinks the word cleared is not part of the string as you've terminated it with double-quotes *beforehand*. You then appear to be starting a new string immediately *after* the word cleared.

To use double quotes (aka speech-marks) within a string, you'll need to double them up like so:

```
Range("H21").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(""cleared"",'mortgage'!A2:F12,4,FALSE)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes around cleared **(DOES NOT WORK)**:

```
Range("H21").Formula = "=VLOOKUP('cleared','mortgage'!A2:F12,4,FALSE)"
```

**EDIT** : Correction made by OP :

*Excel uses single quotes only on the sheet name, not to denote a string literal*

Comment: Excel uses single quotes only on the sheet name, not to denote a string literal.

Comment: You're right, I completely forgot. I'll edit my comment with your correction to make it more visible, in the case someone makes a similar error.

Answer (score 0):

Or another option:

1. Write the working formula in Excel.
2. Select the cell with the
   formula.
3. Run the following code:

---

```
Sub TestMe
     debug.print selection.formula
End Sub
```

---

4. Check the immediate window - that's the formula you are using in Excel.
5. If you want useful formula, that you can actually copy+paste in your VBA code, use this:

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub PrintMeUsefulFormula()

    Dim strFormula  As String
    Dim strParenth  As String

    strParenth = """"

    strFormula = Selection.Formula
    strFormula = Replace(strFormula, """", """""")

    strFormula = strParenth & strFormula & strParenth
    Debug.Print strFormula

End Sub
```

---

6. Check the immediate window.

Comment: In this instance, that won't help at all, as the returned text is `=VLOOKUP("cleared",mortgage!A2:F12,4,FALSE)`

Comment: @CLR - I knew I was missing something from this answer, some months ago - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43050331/formula-is-giving-error-when-i-add-text/43050563#43050563